# Material UI Custom theme color assign Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I created my own custom theme and I'm trying to assing one of the colors I created to a button, but when I'm trying to set it as:

`color={theme.pallete.lightGrey}`

I'm getting this error:

```
No overload matches this call
Overload 1 of 3, '(props: { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses> | undefined; color?: "inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning" | undefined; ... 9 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & Pick<...> & CommonProps & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
```

Does this means that you can't assign custom colors to the color attribute? Only through styling

Answer (score 4):

If you are using typescript use the global theme approach
in this case,

1. I have 2 custom colours which are `neutral` and `backgroundSecondary` so you need to register the  types in material UI types

```
    declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
      interface CustomPalette {
        neutral: {
          main: string;
          contrastText: string;
        };
        backgroundSecondary: string;
      }
      interface Palette extends CustomPalette {}
      interface PaletteOptions extends CustomPalette {}
    }
```

2. Then register that button show be able to read the custom colors

    In my case I only need `neutral` to be read by the Button component so you do this

```
declare module "@mui/material/Button" {
  interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    neutral: true;
  }
}
```

3. You set up your `theme` (in most cases this would have already been setup)

```
let theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "some-color",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "some-color",
    },
    error: {
      main: "some-color",
    },
    neutral: {
      main: "#fff",
      contrastText: "#002255",
    },
    backgroundSecondary: "#f8fafc",
  },
});
```

4. Finally the usage

```
<Button variant="outlined" color="neutral"> Click Me</Button>
```

Comment: Hi can you please explain in which files do you place the "declare module" parts

Comment: @LylePhillips you should add it in the same file as your theme. I place mine at the top before declaring the theme

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Really helped me! What if I want to use `backgroundSecondary` across all mui components?

Comment: @LylePhillips it is accessible across all the mui components. but for some like buttons, you'll need to and some other types in other not to have typescript errors